# Given the quarter name return the start and end dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a string like "2015-Q1". What is the best way to return the start date and end date of the given quarter?

Input:
2015-Q1

Expected Output:
(2015-01-01,2015-03-31)

Comment: How is this a pandas question? Please provide a Series/DataFrame input and the matching expected output.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def func():
    quarter = {
        'Q1' : ['01-01', '03-31'],
        'Q2' : ['04-01', '06-30'],
        'Q3' : ['07-01', '09-30'],
        'Q4' : ['10-01', '12-31']
    }
    
    quarter_input = input()
    
    goal_first = quarter_input[:-2] + quarter[quarter_input[-2:]][0]
    goal_last = quarter_input[:-2] + quarter[quarter_input[-2:]][1]
    
    return (goal_first, goal_last)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary keyed on Q1-4. For each key, assign the beginning and end dates for that quarter. Then:

```
Q = {'Q1': ('01-01', '03-31'), 'Q2': ('04-01', '06-30'), 'Q3': ('07-01', '09-30'), 'Q4': ('10-01', '12-31')}

def quarter(sd):
    yy, qq = sd.split('-')
    b, e = Q[qq]
    return f'({yy}-{b},{yy}-{e})'

print(quarter('2015-Q1'))
```

**Output:**

```
(2015-01-01,2015-03-31)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary with start and end dates with the month for each quarter and use the last 2 characters of the string as key

```
a={'Q1':['01-01','03-31']}
b='2015-Q1'
for i in a[b[-2:]]:
    print(b[:-2]+i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_quarter_date(quarter):
    year,quarter=quarter.split("-")
    year=int(year)
    quarter_map={"Q1":1,"Q2":4,"Q3":7,"Q4":10}
    quarter=int(quarter_map[quarter])
    start=pd.to_datetime(str(year)+"-"+str(quarter)+"-01")
    end=pd.to_datetime(str(year)+"-"+str(quarter+3)+"-01")-pd.DateOffset(days=1)
    return start,end
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have a [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) tag, I imagine you're looking for a pandas approach.

Assuming a DataFrame `df` with a `quarter` column, you could use [`PeriodIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.html) with the `start_time` and `end_time` attributes. As the end time has the time `23:59:59.999999999`, we can [`normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) it to only keep the date:

```
p = pd.PeriodIndex(df['quarter'], freq='Q')
df['start'] = p.start_time
df['end'] = p.end_time.normalize()
```

output:

```
   quarter       start         end
0  2015-Q1  2015-01-01  2015-03-31
1  2015-Q2  2015-04-01  2015-06-30
```

used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'quarter': ['2015-Q1', '2015-Q2']})
```